# How to insert data into two tables in rails at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, omniauth

I am trying from last 2 days to figure out this problem but no avail till now. I am working on omniauth in rails and I have integrated the omniauth authentication in my site but I want to create seperate table for all providers.I have two tables 1: user and other is auth_provider
1: user will contain user data 
2: auth_provder will contain user_id with social media provider authentication details.

I have created has_many association from user to auth_providers.

Now I want to insert the data in both tables so that first the would create entry in user table with some fields and then it should take the newly insert record entry and insert this id with other data into auth_providers table. I know this thing is possible but I am unable to find any example or code. I am just searching and trying from last 2 days but still no success. I want to do it using associations and I have also used nested_attributes but still no success.

Here is my code

user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable,
    :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook,:twitter,:linkedin]
  has_many :organizations_users
  has_many :auth_providers
  has_many :organizations, through: :organizations_users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :auth_providers
    def active_for_authentication?
    # Uncomment the below debug statement to view the properties of the returned self model values.
    super && self.active && self.exp_alert == false
  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    exist = where(email: auth.info.email).first
    if exist
      existing_user = exist["id"]
      Auth_provider.where(provider: auth.provider, social_uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |auth_provider|
      auth_provider.provider =  auth.provider
      auth_provider.social_uid = auth.uid
      auth_provider.social_token = auth.credentials.token
      auth_provider.user_id = existing_user
      end
    else
      #@organization.users.create(first_name:params[:first_name])
      names = auth.info.name.strip.split(" ")
      first_name = names[0]
      last_name = names[1]

      params = { user: {
    email: 'abc@abc.com', auth_providers_attributes: [
    { provider: 'facebook' },
    { social_token: 'asfasf2342432' },
    { social_uid: 'asfdaf23242'} # this will be ignored
    ]
  }}
user = User.create(params[:user])    

              end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end

  def self.find_or_create_from_auth_hash(auth_hash)
    user = where(provider: auth_hash.provider, uid: auth_hash.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.first_name =  auth_hash.info.nickname
      user.active = 'true'
      user.admin=='false'
      user.exp_alert = 'false'
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.token =  auth_hash.credentials.token
      user.email =  auth_hash.info.email
      user.secret =  auth_hash.credentials.secret
      user.skip_confirmation!
    end
    user
  end

  def self.linkedin_hash(auth_hash)
    user = where(provider: auth_hash.provider, uid: auth_hash.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.first_name =  auth_hash.info.first_name
      user.last_name =  auth_hash.info.last_name
      user.active = 'true'
      user.admin = 'false'
      user.exp_alert = 'false'
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
      user.token =  auth_hash.credentials.token
      user.email =  auth_hash.info.email
      user.skip_confirmation!
    end
    user
  end

  def inactive_message
    "Your Account has not been active yet."
  end

  def after_confirmation
    super
    self.update_attribute(:active, true)
  end
end
```

auth_providers model

```
class Auth_provider < ApplicationRecord
devise :database_authenticatable
belongs_to :user

 accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

Response from facebook is this

```
#<OmniAuth::AuthHash credentials=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash expires=true expires_at=1517924507 token="EAAdDsC4F0CCLq95eo81qfaMVVs0zeNgqtRqUF9ufZB3gK609NY3aiikJ9AvE8zSB63WFcG0E6NBFNIWf00DjgHNlsQHCd2D26uxJ1ongQ5YBJZCeuZAOas2SEYlRwPYhctfiEVVdbadOyA3QeL50JHIA5dKa3xdfK5Efw9Y"> extra=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash raw_info=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash email="testing@gmail.com" id="35232364989259" name="John">> info=#<OmniAuth::AuthHash::InfoHash email="testing@gmail.com" image="http://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/35489/picture" name="John"> provider="facebook" uid="354814524989259">
```

Comment: will you create user from any controller first?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding you right, could you do something like:

```
...
user = User.create(the_user_attributes)
user.auth_providers.create(the_auth_provider_attributes)
...
```

This should work, creating a user, then an auth provider belonging to them.

You can also use `User.new` and `user.auth_providers.build` if you need to manipulate either a little ahead of saving, and they'll be persisted when you call `save` on the user.

---

**Update**

To split the code into readable chunks, I'd suggest something like the following:

**user.rb**

```
# update: you're in the user model, so no need to specify the model again in the line below
user = create(user_attributes_from_auth(auth))
user.auth_providers.create(provider_attributes_from_auth(auth))

private

def user_attributes_from_auth(auth)
  { first_name: auth.info.nickname,
    token: auth_hash.credentials.token,
    etc: etc }
end

def provider_attributes_from_auth(auth)
  { a_similar_approach_as: user_attributes_from_auth }
end
```

So, in a nutshell, you use the first two lines in there ^^ to create a user from a hash of attributes, then do the same for the auth provider.

This is nice and readable, and not actually far off what you're currently doing. Have a go and see how you get on - hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your Answer. I have commented out the code because I am not sure about its syntax because let suppose I have 10 fields to insert I want to insert 5 in users and 5 in auth_providers and I don't know how to do it using
users.auth_providers.create() can you help me?

Comment: Have you got an example of the `auth` response you could add to your answer? That'd be dead handy to put something together :) I'll update my answer with a little more info now!

Comment: you mean omniauth callback controller code? Actually I want to do my task in one call that's why I am careful about this.

Comment: Nope - just what's being passed in as `auth` to the `from_omniauth` method (i.e. the response from the provider).

Comment: you are doing two seperate call brother. I need one call to save the database 
user = create(user_attributes_from_auth(auth))
user.auth_providers.create(provider_attributes_from_auth(auth))

This code first create user then create auth_provider. What is special in this code?

Comment: added the response from facebook.Please check the edited question.Thanks.

Comment: Ah I see - I'd initial thought that was your intention, but was led to think otherwise by this sentence _"Now I want to insert the data in both tables so that first the would create entry in user table with some fields and then it should take the newly insert record entry and insert this id with other data into auth_providers table."_ Let me have a think :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160801/discussion-between-john-and-srack).